running asp.net intranet application on localhost asking for authentication
I have an intranet application written int ASP.net core, when I run this application on localhost, I get a pop window asking me to authenticate and once I enter my domain name\my username and password then it authenticates me and lets me run the application. Basically, I enter my Windows username and password and then I can see the application. Below is the screen of what I am getting:

this is what I tried:

went to the folder where the application resides
right click on it and click on the properties
properties->Security tab and gave full control to myself. Below is the screenshot:


This is what I have in web.config file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <runtime>
 
  </runtime>
</configuration>

this is my IISExpress settings:

This is my startup.cs file:
public class Startup
 {
     public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
     private const string DefaultConnection = "DefaultConnection";
     public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
     {
         Configuration = configuration;
     }
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
         services.AddDbContext<AckPackage.Data.AckContext>(options =>
             options.UseSqlServer(
                 Configuration.GetConnectionString(DefaultConnection)));
         services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
         {
             // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
             options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
             options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
         });
         //services.AddAuthentication(options =>
         //{
         //    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         //    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         //});
         services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddNegotiate();
         services.AddAuthorization(options =>
         {
             options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
         });
         services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
         services.AddControllersWithViews();
         services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
         services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
         services.AddSession(options =>
         {
             options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
             options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
             options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
         });
         services.AddRazorPages();
         //services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
         services.BindingAppServices(Configuration);
         services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormOptions>(x =>
         {
             x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
             x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; // In case of multipart
         });
     }
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
     {
         if (env.IsDevelopment())
         {
             app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
         }
         else
         {
             app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
             // The default HSTS value is 30 days.
             app.UseHsts();
         }
         app.UseHttpsRedirection();
         app.UseStaticFiles();
         app.UseRouting();
         app.UseAuthentication();
         app.UseAuthorization();
         app.UseSession();
         app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
         {
             endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                 name: "default",
                 pattern: "{controller=Employee}/{action=Create}/{id?}");
             endpoints.MapRazorPages();
         });
         // app.MapRazorPages();
     }

any help will be greatly appreciated.

could you please share are you using windows authentication with the application. because I can see you have set the <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
in config file. this can be the reason you are getting prompt. could you try setting it to false. and share the program.cs file

This application is an intranet application. This is not a public facing application. I am getting employees name from active directory in this application and displaying those names. In order to do that, I need windows authentication.

so would you like to ignore the authentication prompt ?

I dont want the authentication prompt. I posted my startup.cs file in my question above.

could you try this setting image

I will try this setting that you mentioned in your comment. That option is disabled for me. I need to talk to my networking team to enable that option.

this option will allow you to use the windows credential to login to the site without entering username password

@Jaspal Panchal, The image that you sent me might work, but my networking team is not letting me do this. is there any workaround on the coding side.

I can make the change in program.cs so that it suppresses the authentication window.

in my opinion on way to use is this internet option or you could use group policy

@Jaspal Panchal, Is it possible that browser can auto log me in. Can I put credentials somewhere in program.cs or config file  so that the browser can auto log me in. That would help me a lot.

there is no option like this in my opinion

This almost assuredly isn't a file permission issue.  But it could be a couple of things that you'll need to check.

It could be a development certificate issue.  Are you running in https mode, or just http?  Do you load any certificates?
It's possible and probably the most likely scenario, is you're hosing it in IIS rather than IIS Express, or from the command line, and the IIS settings are setup for Windows Authentication.

Step one would be to try to host it from the command line / terminal.
Navigate to the root of your project (where the csproj is located) and type
dotnet run

And see if it'll host it - and run it and remove the authentication issue.  If it does, then you have a good lead on the culprit.
EDIT
Based on the new screenshots and information, it sounds like you are attempting to automatically log in the user to their intranet (active directory??) username, so that you can utilize this in some way.
Give this a shot:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio
Also note, that I've had countless issues getting AD authentication, even simple windows user auth, to work with IIS Express,  you may want to switch over to actual IIS (which can be installed on your machine if it's not following this link)
https://csharp-developer.com/step-by-step-guide-setting-up-iis-on-windows-11/
If you're not on windows 11, there are similar guides on getting it setup for your version of windows.  Also:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-8.0
To host your dotnet core project in IIS instead of IIS express, I originally followed this guide, so that I knew the ins and outs...after going through it once it's a breeze
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-8.0

I put the screenshot of the IISExpress in my original question. I also put my config file. May be, you can see that setting. please let me know if you need any additional details.

I edited my answer to give you some more detail.  You're using Active Directory yes?

Yes, I am using Active directory.

Unfortunatly it's a complicated question, but the links in my answer should help out a bunch.  A lot of it depends on how your Active directory is exposed, whether it's in mixed mode or not, and how the browser (which browsers you support) communicate with the AD Tenant.  What you're looking for though, is for ASP.NET core to automatically grab the authenticated user, and auto log them in so they never see the popup.  I think the second link at the learn-microsoft site walks you though that.

I dont want to host my application on IIS. I just want to run and debug the  code. IISExpress is good for this debugging. As soon as I run the code, I get the prompt to enter all the credentials, I don't want to do this again and again. I don't know what to do. The application works fine when I enter the credentials

Did you go through this link?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

I think:  If you checked the box to enable anonymous access in your IIS Express settings, then handled anon users in your application code, rather than letting IIS attempt to authenticate them you'd be fine, and it'd all work how you think it'll work

(Edited based on new information)
That is a Basic Authentication modal popup - the browser shows that when the web server sends headers indicating that Authorization is required and that it accepts Basic Authentication .  (Like this:  How to display HTTP 401 basic authentication dialog)
Windows Authentication is how IIS implements Basic Authentication - it takes the username/password provided in response to the 401 challenge and actually tries to use those credentials to whatever Active Directory server(s) your web server is configured to use.
If you want your app to NOT prompt for username/password in this manner, enable Anonymous Authentication and disable Windows Authentication.

I put the screenshot of the IISExpress in my original question. I also put my config file. May be, you can see that setting.

Unfortunately this answer contains several wrong statements. 1. Any challenge-response authentication methods (NTLM/Kerberos/Basic) shares the same prompt, so you cannot call it "Basic Authentication modal popup". 2. Windows authentication (NTLM/Kerberos) has nothing to do with Basic authentication (as they use completely different ways to handle password verification). 3. The prompt can be suppressed for Windows authentication, so suggesting anonymous isn't the answer.

Guess it's been way too long since I did any IIS administration for me to be giving advice about it.  Oh well.
